# Custom Button - RetURL Working in Chrome but not IE

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, visual-workflow, controller-extension, url

I have a custom button on a record page that initiates a Visual Workflow, sets a couple parameter values, defines the finishlocation for the flow to end on a Visualforce page.

For whatever reason, the button works fine when I'm in Chrome, but ignores the retURL in Internet Explorer.  It doesnt throw any errors, and the flow completes correctly, but it skips over the visualforce page completely.

Any idea what would cause this?

Below is a screenshot of the Custom Button:

[image]

Here is the button URL:

```
/flow/Approval_Record_Creation_v2_0?vMId={!Matter__c.Id}&vUserName={!$User.Username}&retURL=apex/appFlowPagev2?id={!Matter__c.Id}&type=Matter
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is this part:

`/appFlowPagev2?id=`

Try replacing the slash with `%2F`, the question mark with `%3F` and the equals with `%3D` so it looks like

`%2FappFlowPagev2%3Fid%3D`

In fact, you may want to ensure all the parameters are properly URL-Encoded. [This](https://www.urlencoder.org/) page can help you there.

PS: if `&type=Matter` is a part of the retURL and not a new parameter, then the `&` and the `=` will have to get encoded too.